# Getting an error on my foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Here is the code:

```
<?php

//Starting session

session_start();

//Includes mass includes containing all the files needed to execute the full script
//Also shows homepage elements without customs

require_once ('includes/mass.php');

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if (isset($username))

{   

//Query database for the users networths

$sq_l = "SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY worth";

$sql_query_worth = mysql_query($sq_l);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query_worth))

      {

         $dbusername = $row['username'];

         $dbworth    = $row['worth'];

            foreach ($dbusername as $dbuser)

                {
                    echo ". USER: ".$dbuser." Has a networth of:  ".$dbworth;

                }
      }               
}

?>
```

There are three results. And here are the errors.

Here is the error msg:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mogul\richlist.php  on line 32

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mogul\richlist.php on line 32

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mogul\richlist.php on line 32

Comment: It seems that `$dbusername` is not an array.

Comment: What's that `foreach` for? Isn't `$dbusername`` a string?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The error message is pretty clear, the loop doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: It is :) I just checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you aren't passing an array to the foreach loop. Try this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query_worth))
{
    $dbusername = $row['username'];
    $dbworth    = $row['worth'];
    echo "USER: ".$dbusername ." Has a networth of:  ".$dbworth;              
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just change:

```
        foreach ($dbusername as $dbuser)

            {
                echo ". USER: ".$dbuser." Has a networth of:  ".$dbworth;

            }
```

to:

```
echo ". USER: ".$dbusername." Has a networth of:  ".$dbworth;
```

Answer (score 1):

`foreach()` iterates over an array. Most likely `$dbusername` is a string instead, which means that you should get rid of the `foreach()` and just echo `$dbusername` directly instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate through a string like an array - foreach requires array() input

Answer (score 0):

No need for your `foreach` loop ; this should work better :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query_worth))
{
  $dbusername = $row['username'];
  $dbworth    = $row['worth'];
  // The username is in $dbusername
  // And the worth is in $dbworth
  // So, just use those :
  echo ". USER: ".$dbusername." Has a networth of:  ".$dbworth;     
}
```

Bascially :

- `mysql_fetch_assoc` fetches the data of the current row into `$row`
- which means `$row` is an array, that contains the `username` and `worth` keys
- you are assigning the values of those two array entries to `$dbusername` and `$dbworth`

  - which now contains strings
  - and can be used directly : they don't contain any sub-array.

If you want to get a better look to what your variables contain, you could use `print_r`, or `var_dump` ; for instance, like this :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query_worth))
{
  var_dump($row;)
  $dbusername = $row['username'];
  $dbworth    = $row['worth'];
  var_dump($dbusername, $dbworth);
  echo ". USER: ".$dbusername." Has a networth of:  ".$dbworth;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the foreach there? Thats not an array. You should have this outside the foreach.

`echo ". USER: ".$dbuser." Has a networth of:  ".$dbworth;`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `foreach` incorrectly. It expects an array as the first argument. In this case just remove the foreach as you already have a while loop iterating through your database query results.